# How to plot array with condition (r < 1.5*rs)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm coding photons orbiting a black hole. When the photons go right into the black hole, the trajectory is really weird due to a division by zero. I'd like to ignore the photons of my array with r < 1.5*rs but I don't know how

I've tried using while True and if, it didn't work

```py
h0=[t0, r2, theta, phi2, pt2, pr2, ptheta, pphi2] 

T = np.linspace(0, 1000, 9000)

zz=odeint(func, h0, T, args=(rs,))

r22 = zz[:, 1]
theta22 = zz[:, 2]
phi22 = zz[:, 3]
pt22 = zz[:, 4]
pr22 = zz[:, 5]
pphi22 = zz[:, 7]

def sph2cart(r, phi, theta):
    X = r * np.cos(phi) * np.sin(theta)
    Y = r * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
    Z = r * np.cos(theta)
    return(X, Y, Z)

X2, Y2, Z2 = sph2cart(r22, phi22, theta22)

plt.plot(X2, Y2, Z2, 'g')
```

I don't think you really need the code to help me, but does anyone know how to plot X2, Y2, Z2 for radius r < 1.5*rs (rs is defined in the code)?

Comment: Did I answer your question? Any other problems need to be clarified?

Comment: @Novice thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I don't really know where to write it.. I'm really just a beginner and so I'd really appreciate it if you could specify where exactly what to write ¿ thanks ;)

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my answer to clarify what I think you need

Answer (score 2):

Numpy has built in masks which work quite well

```
r=np.arange(20)
r_mask = np.ma.masked_where(r < 10 , r)
```

So, since you want to generate X,Y, and Z values only when r<1.5*rs (i think you said it the opposite way at one point, but you'll just need to flip the sign in any case), your code could look like this

```
import numpy as np
h0=[t0, r2, theta, phi2, pt2, pr2, ptheta, pphi2] 

T = np.linspace(0, 1000, 9000)

zz=odeint(func, h0, T, args=(rs,))

r22 = zz[:, 1]
theta22 = zz[:, 2]
phi22 = zz[:, 3]
pt22 = zz[:, 4]
pr22 = zz[:, 5]
pphi22 = zz[:, 7]

def sph2cart(r, phi, theta):
    X = r * np.cos(phi) * np.sin(theta)
    Y = r * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
    Z = r * np.cos(theta)
    return(X, Y, Z)

r22_masked = np.ma.masked_where(r22 > 1.5*rs , r22)

X2, Y2, Z2 = sph2cart(r22_masked, phi22, theta22)
```

This would generate X2,Y2, and Z2 values only for the unmasked values of r22 (aka where r22 is less than 1.5*rs

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it still isn't working, I don't get it. Anyways have a good day!

Comment: If you gave an example dataset I could test it out myself and help